# How to split a value and insert new row in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following data frame:

```
      id  sub_id  timestamp            dist     time_dif     speed     status
   1   1   1      2016-07-01 00:01:00  20       00:01:00     0.0075    True
   2   1   1      2016-07-01 00:01:59  29       00:00:59     0.3450    True
   3   1   1      2016-07-01 00:03:00  30       00:01:00     0.0987    True
   4   1   2      2016-07-01 00:03:59  21       00:59:00     0.5319    True
   5   1   2      2016-07-01 00:05:00  40       00:01:00     0.0076    False
```

In the above data frame, status = False , whenever a distance>30.

I would like to have suggestions to create a function or a way, so that whenever status is "false", that means distance > 30, (in the above data frame, row 5) I can perform following operations:

**Handling the row where status = False (ROW 5)**

The value under "dist" in row 5 (Where status = False, dist = 40) becomes 30, because 30 is the threshold distance and it cant be more than 30.
So, 40 - 30 = 10, this extra 10 should be shifted to next row.

"status" becomes "True" (as dist = 30)

"speed" remains the same,

"id", "sub_id" remains the same

"time_diff" has a new value, since we have speed and distance in row 5, time can be calculated

"timestamp"  should also change, if we calculate time_diff, we could add the time_diff to the value of "time" in row 4 and get new timestamp for row 5.

**Handling the following row (ROW 6)**

Now row 6 or a following row should be inserted in the data frame whenever dist >30 / status = False, so that whatever extra distance was there in previous row comes into this new row.

In the above example, "dist" under row 6 has the value (40-30) ie 10.

"id" remains the same,

"sub_id" becomes 3 (increases by 1),

Since 10 is now less than 30, "status" should be true.

"speed" remains the same.

"time_diff" will again be calculated with the values of "dist" and "speed" in row 6.

"timestamp" will be calculated too, by adding the "time_diff" to the value of previous row "timestamp"

While the rest of the rows in the data frame follows as usual, until another row with status = False is encountered.

Also, there can be case where "dist" = 70, so in this case the row where dist = 70, should have dist = 30, then the following row should have dist = 40, which is still greater than 30, so again it should only keep 30, and insert the remaining 10 in the following row.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so to make sure I understand correctly, you also overwrite the existing rows when a change occurs?

Comment: @AsheKetchum Yes, the row where status= False, will be overwritten with the new values. Also, following is the creation of new row which will have the remaining distance under "dist" and corresponding values.

Comment: there exists `iterrows()` and `itertuples()` which would allow you to iterate through your dataframe, and then you can use `df.loc[nextRowsIndex]==newRow` to create the new row.

Comment: Also, when you create a new row do you want it to be directly under the row  that it was created from? say you have `[true, false, true, true]`, would the separated component of  `false` be inserted into the 3rd row? or would it be appended at the end?

Comment: @AsheKetchum Yes Yes, that's the thing, it should be directly under that row. And the new row should have incremented "sub_id".

Comment: gimme a few minutes, I'll post an answer :)

Comment: Yes yes no problem. Thank you sooooooooo much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't included the changes to the distance, time and speed fields, but the idea should be similar. Let me know if this works and I'll try to add edits from there. Since it's generally bad to make changes to the object you iterate over, I made a new DataFrame to store the changes in.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
limit = 30
Index = 0
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row[7] == False: # 7 is the index of the status column
        tempRow = list(row[:])
        tempRow[4]=limit # 4 is the index of the dist column
        tempRow[7] = True
        df2.loc[Index] = tempRow
        Index +=1
        tempRow[4] = row[4]-limit
        tempRow[7] = tempRow[7] < limit
        tempRow [2]= row[2]+1 # 2 is the index of the sub_id column
        df2.loc[Index] = tempRow
    else:
        df2.loc[Index] = row
    Index += 1
df2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will work with this and let u know if I find any difficulty. Thank you so much

Comment: This will get you through one iteration

Comment: If you want to deal with the case where dist is 70( more than 30*2), might need to change/combine the first if statement with a while loop